# Context Menu not visible in the editor

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I had created a context menu using org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus . Below is the code of that.

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
     <objectContribution
        adaptable="true"
        id="com.myplugin.gui.popupOnFile"
        nameFilter="*.c"
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
     <action
           class="com.myPlugin.gui.RunOnSingleFile"
           enablesFor="1"
           id="com.myplugin.RunOnSingleFile"
           label="Run MyAction"
           menubarPath="com.myplugin.ide.ui.myToolToolsPopupMenu/myToolsGroup"
           tooltip="Run My Action">
     </action>
  </objectContribution>
</extension>
```

With this RunMyAction was enabled in the project explorer as well as in editor when a .c file was selected.

Now I want to do the same thing with org.eclipse.ui.menus . What I tried is below.

```
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:com.myplugin.ide.ui.myToolToolsPopupMenu/myToolsGroup?after=additions">
     <command
           commandId="com.myplugin.RunOnSingleFile"
           label="Run MyAction"
           style="push">
        <visibleWhen>
           <with
                 variable="selection">
              <iterate
                    ifEmpty="false"
                    operator="or">
                 <adapt
                       type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                    <test
                          property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                          value="*.c">
                    </test>
                 </adapt>
              </iterate>
           </with>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

With this Run MyAction is visible as context menu on .c file in the project explorer. But not in editor. Some one let me know how to make MyAction context menu visible when .c file is opened in editor.

Comment: A location of `popup:com.myplugin.ide.ui.myToolToolsPopupMenu` means you are only adding to the popup with that specific id - have you defined this id somewhere? It won't work for an editor because the editor's id is something different.

Comment: Yes this Id is specified in some other plugin to define another context menu